# How to show Word Level Confidence Score in Google Speech API

Tags: node.js, google-speech-api

I have included the Google Speech API in Cloud Functions. I want to get the word level confidence score, so I set 'enableWordConfidence' to true. For some reason, the response doesn't return a confidence score on a word level.

I have tried de-DE and en-US as languageCode, but both didn't work.
Here is the official documentation from Google, but copying that code and running it in the cloud functions also didn't return the word level confidence.
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/word-confidence

Here is the code:

```
const filePath = `gs://PATH_TO_AUDIO.flac`

const audio = {
    uri: filePath,
};

const config = {
    encoding: 'FLAC',
    sampleRateHertz: 16000,
    languageCode: languageCode,
    enableSpeakerDiarization: true,
    enableWordConfidence: true,
    useEnhanced: true,
    enableWordTimeOffsets: true,
    enableAutomaticPunctuation: true,
};

if(languageCode == 'en-US') {
    config.model = 'video'
}

const request = {
    audio: audio,
    config: config,
};

const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

return client
.longRunningRecognize(request)
.then(data => {
    const operation = data[0];

    return operation.promise();
}).then(data => {
    const response = data[0];

    if(response.results) {
        return storeSegmentInMeeting(response.results, noteId);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}).catch(err => {
    return console.error('ERROR:', err);
});
```

I expect to get the confidence score for every word, so any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so this probably won't work unless you switch to "V1P1BETA" version of the library. It has more features, including word-level confidence. I suggest you try that.

I can't tell if you're already doing that, so I'm sharing this just in case.

You need:

```
const speech = require('@google-cloud/speech').v1p1beta1;
```